# Migrating to OpenJDK from Oracle JDK

Tags: maven, jar, open-source, java

I'm working on migrating my project from Oracle JDK to open JDK.

As a part of the development I also want to replace all my Oracle licensed jars with equivalent open source license jars. Now there are quite a lot of it.

The project is maven built and all the dependencies are in the pom file.

I was wondering if there is a way to use my pom.xml file and get all my jars with equivalent open source jars?

As of now I'm manually going to each jar's release notes and checking for an Open source license.

Here when I say Oracle licensed I mean it is not an Open source jar.

Appreciate the help!!!! Cheers !!!

Comment: What is an "Oracle licensed jar"?

Comment: I meant to say, jars that are not open source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this Maven plugin to get a report of all the different licenses your project's dependencies need: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/licenses-mojo.html

You might need to configure the report before the command works as expected: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/examples/selective-reports.html

The next step is then to identify the dependencies that you want to replace and find open source alternatives.

Note: Doing everything open source is commendable (I try it myself) but OpenJDK 6 and 7 didn't receive the same amount of testing and "love" than the official Oracle JDK releases. I had numerous problems with both of them and I stay away from them - they have wasted too much of my time. Things are probably better with OpenJDK 8 but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/